# how to reuse an already implemented method within the same package?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my package I have twoo `activities` and two `fragments`, and in one of the `fragments` i have a method called `protected isClientSetUpReady()`, I want to reuse this method in the second `fragment` by calling it not by re-implementing it again , it is already implemented before.

What i did is, in the second `fragment` i tried to reference it but it is not showing, how to reuse an already implemented method within the same package?

Comment: Is there any relation between the two fragment classes? Is one a sub-class of the other?

Comment: put the method in the activity and call it from the fragment by `((YourActivity)getActivity()).isClientSetUpReady();`

Comment: both of the fragments belong to one activity which has a view pager and action tabs,

Comment: make the function 'public static'

Comment: Define this method at parent level either BaseActivity or BaseFragmentActivity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to access methods from another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576855/java-how-to-access-methods-from-another-class)

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat are sure it is a duplicate?

Comment: @rmaik your question is "how to reuse an already implemented method within the same package?", which is clearly has nothing to do with different activities or fragments, unless you want to use it in a specific way, manner, or behavior, then edit your question with a specific inquiry, cheers

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat "which is clearly has nothing to do with different activities or fragments," NO, it has. see my response/commnet to the user Deepzz below

Comment: @rmaik that's what I'm taking about, your question must be above here NOT in the comments of people answers, what Deepzz did is to answer your question as it appears to be, with a way you will definitely find in the link I attached your question to.

Comment: @rmaik kindly try to respect other people opinions despite it's not your own one, I flaged your last comment as a rude/offensive comment and as a result it's removed now

Answer (score 1):

Make the function

```
 public static void isClientSetUpReady()
{

}
```

Then acces it in other class as

```
 fragment1.isClientSetUpReady();
```

Comment: ok, but inside that method i reference a context using getActivirty. how hat is possible with getActivity

Comment: @rmaik what if you use it like this:public static void isClientSetUpReady(final Activity asd){}

Answer (score 1):

**Keep it simple :**

1. Make an Util class.
2. write your method.
3. use it in both fragment.

like :

```
public class Util {

private Context mContext;

public Util(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

public void isClientSetUpReady()
{
    // do your things
}
```

}

Comment: I dislike to have Util as a class. They tend to become kitchen sink classes. As a package its ok, but not as a class.

Comment: yes I agree with @Dawnkeeper instead a class name like ClientSetUpState could be a good choice , ie to say class name should represent the specific functionality for which they are created.

Comment: thanks for comment. I write Util just to give a name of a class. Just giving a way of the problem by showing an example.