# Boolean value changed but not recognized by if statement

Tags: java, android, class, if-statement, boolean

I have two classes, "class1" and "class2".
When I initialize a boolean called "test" (true) in "class1" and ask for it's value in an if- statement in "class2" everything works fine.
But as soon as I change the value from "test1" to false in a method it doesn't recognize the changes in the if-statement in "class2".

My goal is that the boolean value changes as soon as the rewarded video ends and that the if-statement in class2 recognizes it.

class1:

```
public boolean test1= true; //This is recognized by the if-statement in class2

    ...

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(Placement placement) {
        test1 = false; //this is getting ignored by the if-statement in class2
    }
```

class2:

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();

if(class1.test1){
    // Do something
}else{
    // Do something else
}
```

I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `class1`, then checking the value of `test1` before `onRewardedVideoAdRewarded` can have been invoked.

Comment: @AndyTurner How should I do it right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to access methods from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576855/java-how-to-access-methods-from-another-class)

Comment: @MartinZeitler can you explain it to me in my case? I don't understand it

Comment: How do you know that your code is invoking `onRewardedVideoAdRewarded`? I dont think it's getting there

Comment: @CocoNess this is of course not the whole class, I only showed the method where it changes the "test1" boolen value

Comment: Post the whole class please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use a static variable, your problem would be solved.
make a Class like this:

```
public class MyStatics {
public static boolean test1=true;

}
```

now change class 1 to:

```
 @Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(Placement placement) {
    test1 = false; 
}
```

and keep class 2 as what it is.

> note:

static variable can be accessed everywhere and you dont need to define them again.

> what was your problem?

`class2` ignored `class1`, because when you used "new" class1, in simple words, it's like all your setup reverted to default , and your default was `public boolean test1= true;`

Answer (score 0):

Java is a so-called object oriented language. For all 'static' members defined in a class named, say, 'Movie', there is one of them regardless of how many movie objects are created. But for normal (non-static) members, there's one per created object.

So, when you write `Class1 class1 = new Class1();` you are making a new class1 object, and thus, a copy of every non-static member inside. That means there are at least 2 instances of a class1 object in your runtime, and when you say `test1 = false`, you are updating the test1 field that is part of a different object vs. the one being read by the other class.

The solution? Pass an instance of class1 to some method (or the constructor) of class2, or possibly use a static field or possibly some other solution; you did not paste enough code to make a meaningful guess as to what the best approach is here.